# Heroku PHP Custom Buildpack Gettext Extension

Tags: heroku, gettext, buildpack

I recently customized the Heroku PHP buildpack:
https://github.com/KerryJones/heroku-buildpack-php

I added the config variable and whenever I push to Heroku it says it's building. However, gettext is still not working (and doesn't show on a PHPInfo Page).

Any idea where to go from here?

Comment: The default PHP buildpack is kind of terrible; I'm not sure how to diagnose your problem specifically but I recommend trying Winglian's fork, or [my fork of that](https://github.com/andrewsg/heroku-buildpack-php-foundry) (see especially the documentation on my fork for links and info on how to use Vulcan).  The advantage of doing so is that it will be easy to compile gettext into PHP so that you will not have to add the plugin file to your app source tree, and any problems that arise will appear at compile time.

Comment: Additionally, you should keep in mind that php gettext requires GNU gettext to be installed on the system; if it's not already installed on Heroku dynos (seems likely that it is not) then you'll need to add it to your buildpack or one of the above forks.

Comment: What is Vulcan before I dive in?

Comment: [Vulcan](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-binaries) is a build server that will compile the binaries for your buildpack in the exact same environment that actual Heroku nodes are set up for.  It's essential to use Vulcan to build binaries because otherwise you will link against the wrong versions of libraries etc. when you build locally.  The default PHP buildpack has been severely neglected by Heroku and does not use Vulcan.